# Delphi Firebird UDF return only one char

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, user-defined-functions, firebird2.5

I'm using Firebird 2.5.

I'm trying to write a Delphi XE2 UDF to return some string from some input params.

Here is the function in Delphi:

```
function  FormatRasaSingle(var formatRasa : PChar; var aDenumire : PChar; var aCod : PChar; var aSimbol : PChar; var aTulpina : PChar) : PChar;
var tmpString  : String;
    tmpInteger : Integer;
begin
  tmpString := formatRasa;
  tmpString := StringReplace(tmpString, '#DENUMIRE', aDenumire, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  tmpString := StringReplace(tmpString, '#COD', aCod, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  tmpString := StringReplace(tmpString, '#SIMBOL', aSimbol, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  tmpString := StringReplace(tmpString, '#TULPINA', aTulpina, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  tmpString := 'MAMA';
  tmpInteger := Length(tmpString) + 1;
  Result     := ib_util_malloc(tmpInteger);
  StrPCopy(Result, tmpString);
end;
```

the udf declaration is:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION FORMATRASASINGLE
    CSTRING(255),
    CSTRING(255),
    CSTRING(255),
    CSTRING(255),
    CSTRING(255)
RETURNS CSTRING(255) FREE_IT
ENTRY_POINT 'FormatRasaSingle' MODULE_NAME 'eliteSoftFirebird';
```

when i'm trying to test the function result only the first letter "M".

the lines

```
   tmpString := 'MAMA';
```

is for test only. The real code is before this line.

but is not working.

can someone advice me?

where is the mistake?

Also when I try to input one parameter I get a big error like "error reading data from the connection".

Tks

Razvan

---

how this function must be assuming the double parameters is Numeric (5, 2)?

```
function  FormatRasaMultiple(const formatRasa, aDenumire, aCod, aSimbol, aTulpina : PAnsiChar; aProcent : Double) : PAnsiChar; cdecl; export;
```

the function is exactly the same as previos one BUT have one more numeric parameter.

so far (my old UDF Firebird 1.5) I was using the declaration as "var aProcent : Double" but when I return it has no value.

the UDF is declared like this:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION FORMATRASAMULTIPLE
    CSTRING(255),
    CSTRING(255),
    CSTRING(255),
    CSTRING(255),
    CSTRING(255),
    NUMERIC(5, 2)
RETURNS CSTRING(255) FREE_IT
ENTRY_POINT 'FormatRasaMultiple' MODULE_NAME 'eliteSoftFirebird';
```

Comment: Below there topic starter posted his own "answer" being secondary question how to deal with float numbers. I dup my cmt here 4 history: If you need another question - then post another question. This "answer" would better be deleted. Also, i suspect you should really ask two questions: 1: how will Firebird pass Numeric (5,2) value to UDF - in Firebird's native C++ convention. And then 2: how should that C++ convention be termed in Pascal/Delphi language. The 1st question is obviously not related to Delphi, and the 2nd i believe would be obvious for you as you got answer to the 1st one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chosen wrong datatype jokers.

`String`, `PChar`, and `Char` are not data types in Delphi, but aliases to some actual data types.

Depending on Delphi version and sometimes on compiler settings those can be shortcuts to types such has:

- in Delphi 2009+: `UnicodeString`, `PWideChar`, `WideChar`
- by default in pre-Unicode 32-bit Delphi: `AnsiString`, `PAnsiChar`, `AnsiChar`
- in 16-bit Delphi or with compatibility settings:  `ShortString`, `PAnsiChar`, `AnsiChar`

So using type aliases in type-unsafe DLL project, you gambled that Delphi compiler would choose suitable data types for you. This time the bet failed.

`WideChar` and `UnicodeString` use UTF-16 charset, that for non-Unicode application (or for application, expecting non-Unicode data by protocol) would look as zero-interlaced strings like (in pre-2009 Delphi terms) `'a'^@'b'^@'c'^@` instead of `'abc'`. This, according to ASCIIZ (C) string convention means the string ends after the 1st character.

Hence, you should make you DLL interface match on both side: your sources and Firebird expectations.

- If possible, you may try to say Firebird that those fields and results use UTF-16 charset, but i doubt that Firebird supports it on `CSTRING`.
- You can code your DLL according to Firebird DLL expectations using datatypes `AnsiString`, `PAnsiChar`, `AnsiChar`

I also strongly suggest you reading Delphi help about Unicode in Delphi 2009+ and its implication on compatibility, especially on low-level type-unsafe things like DLLs and pointer maths. There are also few articles on topic in Google.

Using DLLs you remove type safety checks of Delphi compiler, and thus you take the responsibility of ensuring identical binary data representations on both sides of DLL APi. Type aliases like `string`, `char` and `PChar` would make it very fragile and error prone.

---

Additionally i cannot see a calling convention you selected for your DLL entrypoint function. Did you marked your function with `cdecl` keyword or `stdcall` or `register` ? 
Judging by `c:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\include\ib_util.pas` cdecl convention is most probably correct one, but you should check Firebird manuals on this topic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#x86

That is for 32-bit code however, for 64-bit UDFs some another convention would be probably asked for.

---

Now, one more strange thing is your choice of parameters' modes.
Your function has parameters like `var xxx:pointer` and that means double indirection.
Your function expects pointer -> to pointer -> to character and that does not seems correct or rational.
I'd changed `var` qualifier to `const` in your function parameters definitions.

This sample - though it is abandoned and of questionable quality (it suffers from the mantioned above dizzy aliases problem) also supports the idea that `VAR` qualifier is wrong here: http://fireudflib.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fireudflib/src/EMail.pas?view=markup

---

Bringing these points together, i guess your function should look like

```
function FormatRasaSingle(const formatRasa, aDenumire, aCod, aSimbol, aTulpina : PAnsiChar) : PAnsiChar; cdecl; export;
var tmpString  : AnsiString;
    tmpInteger : Integer;
begin
  tmpString := 'MAMA';

  Assert( SizeOf(tmpString[1]) = SizeOf(byte) );

  tmpInteger := Length(tmpString);

  Result     := ib_util_malloc(tmpInteger + 1);
  StrPLCopy(Result, tmpString, tmpInteger);
end;
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.StrPLCopy

Comment: glad to hear. You really should read how Delphi stores different data types on CPU level, and how it does send/receive them from functions.

Comment: unfortunately i'm bad at low lvl programming. i'm trying now to find how can I represent numerical firebird values to Delphi data types. I belive will be differences bettwen Numeric(5,2) and Numeric(15,5)...

Comment: that would probably depend upon database access library, that would translate SQL types to TDataSet VCL types.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, CSTRING represents null terminated C-like string, so you cannot use UTF16 related data types. Try use ANSI types instead.

Comment: that is about returning values, however there seems to be one more trap, with incoming parameters :-)

Comment: It is long time ago, hence I'm not up-to-date, but if you have an input parameter of CSTRING type which is passed as a pointer to ASCIIZ, you have no explicit information about its length - you can scan memory dereferred by this pointer for byte=0x00 only. Hence you cannot pass UTF16, UUID etc...

Comment: i don't recall too, so i cannot say if FB can pass CString in different charset than some OS-default MBCS. Maybe it can or maybe it can not, FB25 is a long road from IB60. However "error reading data from the connection" suggests server crash, and that suggests to me stack corruption. Thus how passing input parameters to a fucntio nmay end up blowing the stack? ;-) PS: come on! I can code UUID in UTF-8 and pass it perfectly. And if i code it in UTF-16 it doesn't matter is it was UUID or "ABCDEFG" - only the charset matters.

Comment: Really, I didn't noticed before.

Comment: Ad UUID: have you tested value containing 0x00?

Comment: that's not it. UUID has different representations: binary and textual. With binary data - ANY binary data - it is bad idea to disguise it as ASCIIZ. Nothign special for UUID - any kind of binary data is equally bad idea here. And with textual UUID representation it does not matter again, either charset allows text exchange or forbids it. And textual UUID is nothing special from, for example, "123.456" as textual float representation. And since you talk about "UTF16, UUID" - textual representation - binary data for 0x00 part in UTF-16 representation would be 0x40, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00

Comment: Failing not because it was UUID but because it was UTF-16 like for any other text

Comment: No, itsn't: UUID is CHAR(16) with CHARACTER SET OCTETS hence you cannot pass it to UDF as CSTRING. That is what I wrote above.

Comment: Oh, i see. I meant UUID in specific FB SQL terms like VARCHAR, and i meant buy UUID the generic concept not related to any particular software. That probably prompted miscommunication.

Comment: I meant a recommended UUID accommodation: _so you're best off using some CHAR(16) or bigger CHAR datatype. Please note that the shorter the storage type, the faster will the indexing work. It is recommended to use the OCTETS as character set for that column_ ([http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq98/](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq98/)